# Optional vs exceptions, controllers vs services

Tags: java, design-patterns, service, controller, option-type

I have JAVA design considerations: I'm struggling between choosing:

1. *services* return Optional values and *controllers* handling the
   non-present case
2. *services* handling directly the non-present case,
   return the real object if present and throw exceptions if not

Are there good practices to help me chose between the 2 approaches?

eg.
**Option 1**
Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Product> findProductById(@PathVariable Long productId) {
        return this.productService.getProductById(productId).map(
                p -> ResponseEntity.ok(p)
        ).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(ResourceType.PRODUCT, "Id", productId.toString()));
    }
```

Service:

```
    public Optional<Product> getProductById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id).map(
                product -> someLogic(product)
        );
    }
```

**Option 2:**
Controller

```
    public ResponseEntity<Product> findProductById(@PathVariable Long productId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getProductById(productId));
    }
```

Service

```
    public Product getProductById(Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id).map(
                product -> lazyLoadProduct(product)
        ).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(ResourceType.PRODUCT, "Id", id.toString()));;
    }
```

For both of these approaches, I have a ControllerAdvice which would eventually transform this Exception in a corresponding end-user-friendly message. So they both "work the same"

Comment: This cannot be answered because it depends on the use case and requirements. Generally speaking, if you don't know what should happen, you should rather lift an exception than doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should only be thrown when there is an unexpected event or circumstance that needs to be handled separately from the core business logic. When searching for a resource, the event in which that resource is not found is an expected outcome and therefore not exceptional.

As such, it is my opinion that you should go with *neither* of these approaches and instead code your controller to be able to handle the returned value of a "not-found" response. (Whether this is an empty list, a special object type, or simply `null` depends on which your implementation could most easily support.)

Comment: Sometimes you must/expect a value and therefore empty result will be consider as error

Comment: @user7294900 Sometimes, sure, but that is rarely the case when you are requesting a remote resource, especially when the remote source is something you don't have direct control over.

Comment: I went for this initially because I was particularly interested in good user feedback. There are sometimes multiple entities involved (eg. product needs profile, profile needs field...) and if all `x.findBy` throw exceptions, the correct `x is not found` is going to be thrown back up to the UI. Without this, the product would hide which dependency retrieval failed, or I would have a disgraceful chain of `if`'s in these underlying services...  This seemed the most "clean way" of doing it but I agree that I'm tickled by the "exception driven" approach

Comment: @Qualaelay There is no such thing as a clean design that is driven by arbitrary exceptions. Exception handling is verbose and computationally expensive, and try/catch blocks are rarely easier to read than if chains. You could also use some form of pattern matching or an `Optional` driven design and it would be preferable to one driven by exceptions. (Stop calling it disgraceful to use if chains. If it matches the flow of your business logic then by all means chain if blocks. It might not look "pretty" but it's easy to look at the code and figure out what you are trying to do.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the service approach as this will give you more flexibility.
There are cases when you need to manipulate response coming from database and apply workarounds. You can apply this logic in service part.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer 2, Handling empty values is part of business logic and should be handle in service,

Such method can be reusable in other places in your application

Also use Optional only in specific cases when necessary